# syncfusion height of dashboard layout

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

I have tried to append a simple DashboardLayoutComponent of syncfusion into a simple react App.

the simple app is striaght forward wrapped a DashboardLayoutComponent and thats it.

However, I saw the result is the height of the DashboardLayoutComponent is not 100% of current window. I have searched the entire document of it and I couldn't find a solution below.

Is it possible to do to config anything so that the height of DashboardLayoutComponent can be 100% of the current window (catering the resize) so that the panel rendered panel can fully cover the background?

this is the snippet used to render DashboardLayoutComponent

```
<DashboardLayoutComponent
  //mediaQuery="max-height: 100%"
  cellSpacing={cellSpacing}
  columns={10}
  showGridLines={true}      
  allowResizing={true}
  allowDragging={true}
  cellAspectRatio={1.1}
>
  {PageLayout.map((grid, index) => (
    <div
      className="e-panel"
      id={grid.id}
      key={grid.id}
      data-row={grid.row}
      data-col={grid.col}
      data-sizex={grid.sizeX}
      data-sizey={grid.sizeY}
    >
      {grid.id}
    </div>
  ))}
</DashboardLayoutComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, DashboardLayout is rendered based on parent element dimension. If you are not setting height for parent element, it will consider the dashboard panel height as a dashboard element height.

When setting the parent element height as 1000px and the column property as 10. DashboardLayout panels rendered based on (10*10) dimension. Each panels height is 100px. It splits the rows and column based on columns property of DashboardLayout component.

Refer the below link to know more about the DashboardLayout structure.
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/dashboard-layout/setting-size-of-cells/

Refer the below link to set the height of DashboardLayout component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6zgydw?file=index.css

When using row, col property of DashboardLayout, you can adjust the panel position and size. By default, DashboardLayout does not have height property.

Refer the below sample to adapt the DashboardLayout in screen.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6zgydw-zuraci?file=index.css

To learn more about the DashboardLayout component. Refer the below link.

UG documentation-https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/dashboard-layout/getting-started/

Demo link-https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/dashboard-layout/default

API reference-https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/dashboard-layout/